# Replacing the Door?

Tags: doors, replacement, door-frame, weatherstripping, weatherproof

I'm looking to replace a door with unconventional dimensions, approximately 45 x 80 in rough opening, leading to a covered and screened patio. The primary issue prompting the replacement is significant air leakage around the existing door on all side.There is no traditional weather stripping in the center and air just blows through the house. Considering the specific requirements of this situation, what tailored options or ideas do you recommend for replacing this odd-sized door? I'm particularly interested in solutions that prioritize effective insulation and sealing to address the air leakage problem. Additionally, any insights on materials, styles, and features that would enhance the overall energy efficiency and quality of the replacement door would be greatly appreciated.

This door is primarily used for moving appliances in or out of the kitchen as needed.

[image]

Comment: All doors leak air around them.  That is what weather stripping is for.

Comment: Try calling a door and window specialist in your area.  Often they can replace the weatherstriping.  The cost is far less than a new door.

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear. What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: Do you want to replace it because of the size or leaks? Why is it an odd size, what is meant by odd?  Replacing with a different sized door will be very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the weatherstripping comments, but if you do a new door, 42” isn’t an outlandish size (from a real door supplier — forget evil orange). And someone in the future might appreciate such a wide door for furniture moving.

Alternately, a narrow sidelight and a more typical door would be an option. However, sidelights are less secure than a solid door due to prying/smashing attacks.